# Duplicate order numbers in Cart Throb

Tags: cartthrob, database, url-title

We've got quite high traffic cart throb site which occasionally gets duplicate order numbers. The most recent one was when 2 orders were placed at exactly the same time (to the second). Both orders have been given the same title and url_title, but obviously have different entry IDs in the database.

This must be a Cart Throb bug? Has anyone else come across this before?

This causes problems with the sales reporting so we really need to find a fix. Anyone from Cart Throb able to offer any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Cart Throb's changelog shows that 2.61 includes a fix for this issue.